# Regarding 'gui' and 'command-line' tag

Tags: discussion

Given [Jeff's answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/making-questions-more-generic/370#370), does it make sense to continue using the gui and command-line tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff was merging two questions which shared a common theme. However, I think Jeff was merely trying to merge two duplicate questions, because the content was nearly identical. It appears that you purposely asked the [second question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5268/how-do-i-merge-two-avi-files-into-one) and duplicated the content to demonstrate a point, which is fine. He was not attempting to merge tags, which is a far different topic.

Another way to view this question is "Should we merge the GUI and Command-line tags?" My answer there is a firm No.

The user interface is an important way to access the operating system. There are major differences between any GUI and a command-line interface, and interfacing with X/Gnome/KDE is completely different the using a shell. I would also argue that there is often very little in common between a GUI and a CLI solution.

We need a way to distinguish between these two different methods.

It's very common for an organization to manage hundreds of Un*x machines, and not a single GUI among them. Given this environment, it would be wrong to provide a bunch of GUI solutions when they clearly need a CLI solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you implying that the comment I left on Gilles' answer is valid, that one can go ahead and re-ask...?

Answer (score 2):

If we really are going to merge GUI and command-line answers to "how do I do X  with a [gui|command-line]" then it *probably* makes sense to abandon the command-line tag since we already have various tags such as `shell` and `terminal` for other types of `command-line` questions.  The `gui` tag could still be really relevant to questions that are about various graphical user interfaces.

Comment: Seems to be a different, only at the surface related question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Sometimes a program being GUI or command line is an important part of the requirements. If you take Jeff's reasoning to an extreme, we could merge every question into “How do I do something?”

(For what it's worth, I don't think this particular merge should have been done.)

Comment: By this you actually mean that I can go through all questions that actually required the answer to be CLI, and re-ask them, only this time to require GUI. Can you add some justification.

Comment: @Tshepang: No, I mean that for *some* questions requesting a CLI answer, it's fine to ask a separate question with similar requirements except that you want a GUI.

Comment: What are you excluding by *some*? That is, where is it not okay to re-ask?

Comment: @Tshepang: When answers to one of the questions would be mostly useless to people asking the other question and vice versa. The avi file merging is borderline: the answers are mostly disjoint (which suggests the questions should be separate), but a lot of people wouldn't mind either way (which suggests the questions should be merged).